# run swing application without DSN creation

Tags: java, swing, awt, installation, dsn

How to run the swing application without creating the DSN on the client

I am working on  a swing application in which i have to  give the mdb database to 
the  client with password protection , i dont want the need to create DSN on client side

Is there any possible way to give the database path in the coding part rather than 
specifying the DSN name. because DSN creation is a complicated task for client.

Comment: IP Address instead of DNS with ODBC ???,

Comment: ITS DSN (data source name ) created to use ODBC i dont need that want to give the path of database in my hard code programm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

USE below code to create your connection:

```
Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};Dbq=c:\\as\\sampleDB.mdb");
```

This might help You.

Comment: @adesh: I don't know about your application, How can i Say about this terms? BTW, You can explain me what this terms are?

Comment: i am running by your code also but its giving error as data source name not found or no default driver specified

Comment: @adesh: Above code is working fine for me... I don't think there's any error in it.