# jdbc odbc connectivity without dsn creation

Tags: java, netbeans, jdbc, dsn, jdbc-odbc

I am trying to make jdbc-Odbc connection  without making the DSN but is throwing the exception. I am using the following code and it is throwing data source name not found no default driver specified exception.

```
try
{
    Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
    Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(
        "Jdbc:Odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver(*.mdb)}; Dbq=d:/new folder/db1.mdb;");
}
catch(Exception ex)
{   
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

suggest me whats wrong in this code.thanks in advance

Comment: Have you added or included the driver in your classpath pr project location?

Comment: data source name not found no default driver specified.

Comment: no polppan i have not included the driver in classpath nor in project location how we have to include it

Comment: Are you using any Tool/IDE for development?

Comment: @adesh [This](http://www.oracledistilled.com/netbeans/adding-java-libraries-to-netbeans-6-9/) might be useful

Comment: suggest me how to include driver in project

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19818/discussion-between-adesh-and-polppan)

Comment: possible duplicate of [odbc connectivity without DSN creation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13283813/odbc-connectivity-without-dsn-creation)

Comment: And other duplicate with accepted answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13247405/run-swing-application-without-dsn-creation